# Python Vasicek model calibration using scipy optimize

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, mathematical-optimization, modeling, calibration

I am trying to set-up a Vasicek calibration routine using python. I thought best to use scipy.optimize but am struggling how to code it up. I have the overall form below.

Anyone who have implemented Vasicek calibration in python? Initial data-table below.

tau = <0.25, 0.50, 1.0, 1.50, 2.0>, and zeroBond = <0.975, 0.949, 0.900, 0.8519, 0.8056>

Update : so given, this formulae :
B = (1 - np.exp(-kappa*tau)) / kappa
A = np.exp((theta-(sigma**2)/(2***(kappa2))) * (B-tau) - (sigma**2)/(4*kappa)*(B***2))
Vasicek = Anp.exp(-r0 * B)

what python function is there, to iteratively solve for 'kappa' such that the variable Vasicek hits a certain value?

```
def py_exact_zcb_Vas_Table(theta, kappa, sigma, tau, zeroBond, r0 = 0):
  length = len(tau)
  B = np.zeros(length)
  A = np.zeros(length)

  Vasicek = np.zeros(length)
  kappa_calib = np.zeros(length)
  theta_calib = np.zeros(length)
  Vasci_calib = np.zeros(length)

  for i in range(0, length, 1):
    B[i] = (1 - np.exp(-kappa*tau[i])) / kappa
    A[i] = np.exp((theta-(sigma[i]**2)/(2*(kappa**2))) * (B[i]-tau[i]) - (sigma[i]**2)/(4*kappa)*(B[i]**2))
    Vasicek[i] = A[i]*np.exp(-r0 * B[i])

    #do while (zeroBond[i] - Vasci_calib[i]) <> 0:
        # change kappa[i] such that I match Vasci_calib[i] with zeroBond[i]



  return pd.DataFrame({'B':B, 'A':A, 'Vasicek':Vasicek, 'kappa':kapp_calib})
```

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verfiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (for example, you haven't defined `xw`), and if you asked a more specific question ("am struggling how to code it up" isn't really a question).

Comment: Is that better?Update : so given, this formulae : B = (1 - np.exp(-kappatau)) / kappa A = np.exp((theta-(sigma2)/(2(kappa2))) * (B-tau) - (sigma2)/(4*kappa)(B2)) Vasicek = Anp.exp(-r0 * B)

what python function is there, to iteratively solve for 'kappa' such that the variable Vasicek hits a certain value?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar) function, in order to find `kappa` which solve the equation `Vasicek(kappa) = target_value`, given the parameters `(tau, sigma, theta, r0)`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

def compute_Vasicek(kappa, tau, sigma, theta, r0):
    B = (1 - np.exp(-kappa*tau)) / kappa
    A = np.exp((theta-(sigma**2)/(2*(kappa**2))) * (B-tau) - (sigma**2)/(4*kappa)*(B**2))
    vasicek = A*np.exp(-r0 * B)
    return vasicek

def objectif_function(kappa, *args):
    return (compute_Vasicek(kappa, *args[1:]) - args[0])**2

# Minimization:
targeted_Vasicek = 10
tau, sigma, theta, r0 = 4, 205, 5, 0
result = minimize_scalar(objectif_function, args=(targeted_Vasicek, tau, sigma, theta, r0), bounds=(0, 100), method='bounded')
print(result)
```

Maybe the `Brent` method would work in your case, using non-random value for the parameters...

Then, you could do:

```
kappa_calib = result.x
vasci_calib = compute_Vasicek(kappa_calib, tau, sigma, theta, r0)
```

and wrap the minimization part in another function, so it can be called from inside the loop

Comment: thanks. I tried to use the method 'brent;, but I got this error message though,  A = np.exp((theta-(sigma**2)/(2*(K**2))) * (B-time) - (sigma**2)/(4*K)*(B**2)) ; ... ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero ........ any ideas?